# Fabric.js image clipTo not working correctly on mobile phones and retina displays

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, retina-display

I have built a small application using fabric.js and encountered a very strange problem on mobile devices.
I have a path that I use in image.clipTo function to clip image to it. It works perfectly on PC, but on mobiles the path is duplicated and offsetted

The code for clipping function:

```
img.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    this.setCoords();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    part.render(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

So this is how it looks on desktop:
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JxUh.png)

And this is how it looks on mobile emulator with the same resolution (it looks the same on actual mobile device):
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYU8z.png)

You can notice that small duplicated rectangle on left. If I move the image to this rectangle it crops perfectly.

You can also see this live on brmk-case-editor.herokuapp.com . To reproduce: click on collage button, select any collage and then double click on any collage part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your mobile device has a device pixel ratio greather than 1.

Fabric uses it as crispness enahancer.

calling `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);` you are killing it and your path gets rendered smaller in a different position. and the image is all clipped away.

What you have to do is:

```
var retina = canvas.getRetinaScaling();
ctx.setTransform(retina, 0, 0, retina, 0, 0);
```

this should help.

Comment: would you mine accepting with the green thick? or it will be listed as unanswered